# How to check if a variable is a dictionary in jinja

Tags: python, jinja2

`set x = {'a':1}`

how to find out if x is a dictionary in jinja? I tried to say if iterable but that can't differentiate between list, string, or dictionary. I want to know if a variable is a dictionary.

Comment: `type(x)==dict`

Comment: Most of the time the variable is passed to the jinja template by your python code. So as developer you need to make sure you pass in the right type of variable. Python is dynamic typing language so developer should be responsible for the correct type. You may share some more info about your use case.

Answer (score 5):

With mapping filter, like

```
{% if x is mapping %} 
do something 
{% endif %}
```